# In vim, how can I automatically maximize the help window

Tags: vim, autocmd

When I display a vim helpfile by running e.g. `:h au`, the help is displayed in a horizontal split window:

[image: vim help]

Currently I always run `Ctrl+w _` but I would prefer the *help buffer* to open in a maximized window automatically.

I've tried to create an autocmd to solve the issue:

```
"Automatically maximize help buffers
augroup filetype_help
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinEnter,FileType help wincmd _
augroup END
```

which only works sporadically.

**EDIT:**

I have done some further debugging.
Opening a certain help page the **first time**, e.g. `:h au` displays it maxmimized when having above augroup in my `.vimrc`.

Closing the helpfiles window via `:q` and then reopening the same helpfile a **second time** causes the help file to be displayed in a split as in the screenshot above.

Closing the helpfiles buffer window via `:bd` and then reopening it, causes it to being displayed maximized as desired.

*How can I rewrite my augroup so that it also maximizes an already opened help buffer?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BufWinEnter` event matches the help filename, so the `help` pattern (which is fine for a `FileType` match) won't work. The `'filetype'` option is only set once for a buffer, so when it is reused (after `:q`, but not after `:bd`), your maximization fails, in the way you've reported.

Instead, have the `:autocmd` match all buffers, and check for the `'buftype'`:

```
augroup filetype_help
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWinEnter * if &l:buftype ==# 'help' | wincmd _ | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: Thank you @Ingo, your modification solved my problem.  
Would you mind explaining the `&l:` and `==#` constructs?
I am unsure what `&l` does and why you used the `#` character in the comparison.

Comment: Great! The `l:` prefix selects the `:setlocal` value; you could also leave it out. `==#` is a case-sensitive comparison. As you see, I try to be very explicit in Vimscript.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve your goal of getting your help buffers to be maximized more simply by putting the following in your .vimrc (or wherever), instead of the augroup/autocmd:

```
:set helpheight=9999
```

Comment: You could explain what makes your solution preferable over the one accepted.
Also, the question asked for help writing an augroup, and not for an ex-command, so you could explain why your solution is preferable compared to the solutions already proposed.

Comment: @jottr, you're the one who asked the question-- my impression is  that my answer achieves your goal ("... the help buffer to open in a maximized window automatically") more simply and directly than the approach you tried.  Is that not the case?  You say you defined your augroup in your .vimrc-- so I think you could put the "set helpheight=9999" there instead, right?   Let me know if I'm really missing something, but if you're just asking me to spell out something that's already clear, I will decline.

Comment: All right, spelled it out.  Still not sure whether I'm missing something.  I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: This solution also seemingly better preserves the position of the main edited document and the cursor within it after closing the help window.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'd like the help window to be horizontally maximized.

Sorry, I can't reproduce your bug (tried on MacVim 7.4-258 and vim 7.4-258), but here are some suggestions:

1. Try changing `wincmd _` to `set winheight=9999` in your augroup script.
2. How about opening the help in a new tab with `wincmd T` instead?

Comment: thank you for trying to help. Please see my edited question above.

Comment: edited the answer.. though I can't seem to reproduce your bug.

Answer (score -1):

```
|CTRL-W_o|      CTRL-W o           close all but current window (like |:only|)
```

Comment: Can you explain more your answer please ?

Comment: when you have splitted the window, clicking the 'CTRL-W  o'  would make current active window only on the vim (others are closed which you could use ':ls' to see them).